# How to determine an 360° angle from relative direction?

Tags: c#, math, angle, direction

I have a minimap on the screen and having problems to determine the angle to a target relative to the camera.

Here is some drawing of what I mean with some examples of camera position and direction:

[image: I describe the problem (hopefully)]

- The black triangles represent the camera.
- The black arrows define their forward direction.
- The blue arrows are the direction to the target (= red dot in the middle) from the camera.
- The circles in the specific cameras define the wanted orientation of its red dot.

Here's my code so far:

```
//Anchored position around minimap circle
void CalculateScreenPos(){
    Vector3 dir = transform.position - cam.position; //xz distance 
    dir.y = 0;
    angle = Angle360(cam.forward.normalized, dir.normalized, cam.right);

    Vector2 desiredPosition = new Vector2(
        eX * -Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.PI/180f) * dir.z, 
        eY * Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.PI/180f) * dir.x
    );

    minimapBlip.anchoredPosition = desiredPosition;
}

public static float Angle360(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Vector3 right)
{
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(from, to);
    return (Vector3.Angle(right, to) > 90f) ? 360f - angle : angle;
}
```

But the angle seems not working properly, found out that it ranges from

> 0° + cam.eulerXAngles.x to 360° - cam.eulerAngles.x

So it works when the cam is never looking to the ground or sky.

How do I get rid of the unwanted added x-eulerAngles by not substracting/adding it again to the angle?

```
angle -= cam.transform.eulerAngles.x
```

is a bad choice as when the result of Angle360 is 360, it gets substracted again, leading immediatly to a wrong angle.

Also the circle can be an ellipsoid, that's why I have put `eX` and `eY` in the desired position that determine the extends of the ellipse.

Comment: Get rid of the z-coordinate in all vectors, and you will just have to call `Vector2.Angle` to get the angle then. The map is a x-y projection of the world, so it shouldn't depend on the height of the camera or the object.

Comment: The world I use is 3d based, so I use the cartesian coordinate system , with x being left/right, y the height and z back/forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

```
angle = Mathf.Atan2(heading.x, heading.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg-Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y;

Vector2 desiredPosition = new Vector2(
    eX * -Mathf.Cos((angle+90) * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 
    eY * Mathf.Sin((angle+90) * Mathf.Deg2Rad)
);
```

Thanks for the help so far and happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what data type you are using e.g. `cam.position`, `cam.heading`, etc. but some general guidance that will help you debug this problem.

1. Write a unit test. Prepare some canned data, both for input (e.g. set `cam.position/cam.heading`, `transform`, etc.) and output (the expected angle). Do this for a few cases, e.g. all the six examples you've shown. This makes it easier to repeat your test, and understand which case isn't working - you might see a pattern. It also makes it easy to run your code through a debugger.
2. Break your functions into logical units of work. What does `Angle360` do? I guess you understand what it is supposed to do, but I think it is really two functions

   1. Get the angle between the two vectors (current direction and target direction)
   2. Rotate map (or something like that)
3. Write tests for those broken out functions. You're just using some library angle difference function - is it behaving as you expect?
4. Name your variables. You have a vector called `right` - what is that? There's no comment. Is it `right` as in 'correct', or as in 'opposite of left'? Why is it `Vector3.Angle(right, to)`, and why not `Vector3.Angle(to, right)`?

Generally you are performing some math and getting tripped up because your code is not clear, things are not well named, and the approach is not clear. Break the problem into smaller pieces and the issue will become obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, appreciate your help!